# Error code when testing with maven on morse code java

Tags: java, morse-code

Im testing my java morse code using Maven. Here's my prompt:

You are to use . to represent dot and - to represent dash. There must be a single space between each Morse code representation of a character and three spaces between words.

I couldn't figure the how to get the right amount of spacing between words and couldn't figure the error on "SOS" output. It's a little hard to read the code line.

input
"SOS"
output
... --- ...
input
"CSC 142"
output
-.-. ... -.-.   .---- ....- ..---

here's my code:

```
public class MorseCode {

    private static final char[] alphabet = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', ',', '.', '?' };

    private static final String[] morse = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".---.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", "-----", "--..--", ".-.-.-", "..--.." };

    private String InputPhrase;
    private static String[] phrase;
    private static int wordlength;

    public MorseCode(String s, String input) {
        // PLACE CODE HERE
        InputPhrase = s;
        wordlength = input.length();
        phrase = new String[wordlength];
        stringToMorse(input); 
    }

    public static String stringToMorse(String input) {
         // PLACE CODE HERE
         char[] chars = input.toCharArray();

         String str = "";
         for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
             for (int index = 0; index < alphabet.length; index++) {
                 if (alphabet[index] == chars[i]) {
                     str = str + morse[index] + " ";
                 }
             } 
         }
         return str; 
    }
}
```

[maven code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAohS.png)

Comment: I can't figure why my output on "SOS" looks the same as the maven test but failed and don't know how to make sure there's 3 space between each word.

Comment: Which character in your input string means that you need to add extra spaces? Can you tell when that character appears and add more spaces to `str`?

Comment: Perhaps your SOS output has an extra trailing space. Your prompt does say "between".

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is adding a trailing space each time it iterates.

`str = str + morse[index] + " ";`

So on the last letter you process, it adds an trailing blank space which causes the SOS test to fail.
Try putting a System.out.println in your code at the end of your method like:

`System.out.println("srt->" + str + "<");`

You'll see the trailing blank space then..

As to putting 3 spaces between words, you can detect a work break by looking for a blank space in the input. As it is your code will not detect a blank space in the input as a blank space is not in your alphabet array.

Try to set a breakpoint and trace through the code, or adding System.outs to help debug it.